# IO action in a when statement

Tags: haskell

Can anyone tell me why I cannot add a IO statement within a do block? This code only prints "test" and then completes execution. The last two lines do not seem to be executing.

```
putStrLn "Do you want to add a task. Press y to add:"
option <- getChar
when (option == 'y') $ do 
  print "test"
  newText <- getLine
  appendFile "todoList.txt" (newText ++ "\n")
```

Comment: Why do you suppose they are not executing? Find a minimal example that demonstrates the problem, since this code is not it. Also, check your whitespace: it looks like there are tabs mixed with spaces, which will certainly do some weird things to you.

Comment: You pressed y and then enter, right? So y followed by a blank line. So getChar reads the y and getLine reads the blank line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getChar` will peak the `y` char but will let the `\n` in the input stream.
So you need to flush the input stream before going further.

Alternatively you can use the `readLn` providing you define a new data type:

```
data Choice = Y | N 
               deriving (Read, Show, Eq)

putStrLn "Do you want to add a task. Press y to add:"
option <- readLn
when (option == Y) $ do
    print "test"
    getLine >>= appendFile "todoList.txt" . (++"\n")
```

Comment: I'm not sure `readLn` is a step in the right direction. You've gone from treating anything other than `'y'` as a negative response to treating anything other than `"Y"` or `"N"` as a run-time error.

Comment: @chepner I was too lazy to define the Read instance to follow this behaviour and left that as an exercise for the OP ;).